# Angular ui-bootstrap: Modal not dismissed on backdrop click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

When using ui-bootstrap version 0.13, the modal is not dismissed in the event of a click to the backdrop. (even if backdrop is not set to 'static')

```
$modal.open({
        ...
        backdrop: true,
        ...
});
```

The problem is illustrated in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tfAekvVVPQstnvt0Fl16?p=preview). The second version of the plunker shows that the same code works on version 0.6 of ui-bootstrap.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last version of ui-bootstrap that was compatible with Bootstrap CSS 2.3.x was ui-bootstrap 0.8.0. So you need to either update Bootstrap CSS to 3.x or stick with ui-bootstrap 0.8.0.

> This version of the library (0.13.0) works only with Bootstrap CSS in version 3.x. 0.8.0 is the last version of this library that supports Bootstrap CSS in version 2.3.x.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/